# how to display data from plist in pdf format in a new view?

Tags: objective-c, pdf, plist

i've been hammering my brain trying to figure this one out and can't find anything in the doc's or on SO that is helpful so far. i have a project that allows the user the input data and save it to a plist. is there a way to display the data that has been stored in the plist in a new view in pdf format? what i am trying to do is to display the recorded data in a new view controller with pdf format so the user can print that list. i know there is a way but i just can't figure it out and i finally threw the towel in and here i am. i will be eternally grateful for any help guys. and girls too.

i can create a new pdf with the following code. i just can't seem to understand how to get the eta from the plist to display.

```
- (IBAction)didClickMakePDF {
[self setupPDFDocumentNamed:@"NewPDF" Width:850 Height:1100];

[self beginPDFPage];

CGRect textRect = [self addText:@"This is some nice text here, don't you agree?" 
                      withFrame:CGRectMake(kPadding, kPadding, 400, 200) fontSize:48.0f];

CGRect blueLineRect = [self addLineWithFrame:CGRectMake(kPadding, textRect.origin.y + textRect.size.height + kPadding, _pageSize.width - kPadding*2, 4) 
                                   withColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"];
CGRect imageRect = [self addImage:anImage 
                          atPoint:CGPointMake((_pageSize.width/2)-(anImage.size.width/2), blueLineRect.origin.y + blueLineRect.size.height + kPadding)];

[self addLineWithFrame:CGRectMake(kPadding, imageRect.origin.y + imageRect.size.height + kPadding, _pageSize.width - kPadding*2, 4) 
             withColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[self finishPDF];

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at `CGPDFContextCreateWithURL`? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html

Comment: @Wain, thanks i went through that class reference, i am able to create a pdf but have no clue how to feed it the data from my plist. any idea where i can find some sample code to take a look at.

Comment: You want a list of text? What is in the plist? An array of strings?

Comment: i have a list of texts that are driven from the textfield. they are strings. and also an image again a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you've got your PDF context and some text loaded from your plist. You need to decide how it will be laid out to be rendered into the PDF. Core Text can make a really nice job of it. The quick and easy route to get you started is:

start by flipping the context

```
CGContextScaleCTM(pdfContext, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(pdfContext, 0.0, -bounds.size.height);
```

draw your text

```
[text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(x, y) withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:48.0f]];
```

where you will obviously want to change:

1. the text content in a loop
2. the `y` position so each line is drawn further down the page
3. the font

Images can be drawn into the context in the same way.

Then, move on to [Core Text](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Overview/Overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH3-SW1) to do a better job with paragraphs of text.

Comment: i can create a new pdf file, but don't know how to get my data from the plist to show instead of just displaying a text or image that are preloaded in the project. that is what i have issues with. i also updated my question with the method i am using to create a pdf.

Comment: thanks a lot for the overview references. i was able to create a pdf from a plist which i placed in project. i am saving the data of my plist into the directory and am able to display that data in a tableview, but what i really want is to read the data of that plist that i have saved and display it as a pdf file. so i am going to initiate another question and would be really cool if you could take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

"When you draw to the PDF context using CGContext functions the drawing operations are recorded in PDF format. The PDF commands that represent the drawing are written to the destination specified when you create the PDF graphics context."

This comes from the same page referenced above: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html

A CGPDFContext is "just" a CGContext. You could set a color in it using "CGContextSetCMYKFillColor" for example or draw text in it using the NSString "drawInRect" method.